# Как использовать статические файлы в Django при DEBUG = False?

Tags: python, django, heroku, развертывание, static

Есть интернет-магазин, написанный с помощью Django и развернут на Heroku.
Мне нужно чтобы админ магазина через админ. сайт Django смог загружать свои изображения и давать описание товару.
При DEBUG = True все идет как надо, но, я для безопасности хочу выключить DEBUG.
Когда я это делаю, сайт не видит те файлы, которые загружает админ.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы изображения появлялись на сайте, когда их загружают с админ. сайта Django при этом, чтобы DEBUG был равен False ?
Вот мой код стат. файлов в settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Вот код в urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Настройки Heroku в settings.py:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Все другие стат. файлы появляются нормально

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: В документации Heroku есть https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets